# Aligning Checkboxes in Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction, style, display, alignment

Consider the following code

```
Manipulate[c,
 Dynamic@Grid[{
    {"Checkbox 1", 
     Row[{Control[{{a, 0, ""}, {1, 0}}], 
       If[a == 1, 
        Control[{{c, {0}, ""}, {1 -> "Edit"}, 
          ControlType -> TogglerBar}], Unevaluated[Sequence[]]]}, Alignment -> Left]},
    {"Checkbox 2", Control[{{b, 0, ""}, {1, 0}}]}
    }, Alignment -> {Left, Right}], ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image]

When I check the first Checkbox, I get

[image]

As one can see, the alignment between the two checkboxes is now off. Any way to fix this? I tried aligning the `Row` and setting `Appearance -> None` within the `Edit` control, but nothing seems to work.

My goal is to get

[image]

Any suggestions/alternative are appreciated.

**Edit:** Using kglr's solution below, and setting `Appearance -> None` in the `Edit` control, I still have two issues. One is that even though the additional vertical spacing I get when Checkbox 1 is selected can be neutralised by the extra `Appearance` condition, I'd still like to have no horizontal spacing, as seen in the following

[image]

Secondly, my code actually has lots of checkboxes and sliders vertically displayed, so this solution would yield a much bigger code and this horizontal offset would look a bit bad overall. These are minor details, but if anyone has any ideas how to solve these issues, please share!

Comment: add the option `ItemSize -> {{7, 7, Automatic}, {3, 3, Automatic}}` to `Grid[]`

Comment: use `{"Checkbox 2", 
 Row[{Control[{{b, 0, ""}, {1, 0}}], 
   If[a == 1, "", Unevaluated[Sequence[]]]}, Alignment -> Left]}` in the second row of `Grid`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** Remove the automatic content padding from `Setter`s in `TogglerBar` to eliminate changes in item sizes:

```
noPadding = Style[#, DefaultOptions -> {Setter -> { ContentPadding -> 0}}] &; 

Manipulate[c, 
 Dynamic @ Grid[{
   {"Checkbox 1", Control[{{a, 0, ""}, {1, 0}}], 
     If[a == 1, 
      noPadding @ Control[{{c, {0}, ""}, {1 -> "Edit", 2 -> "blah"}, TogglerBar}], 
      Unevaluated[Sequence[]]]}, 
  {"Checkbox 2", Control[{{b, 0, ""}, {1, 0}}]}}, 
   Alignment -> {Left, Right, Left}], 
 ControlPlacement -> Left, Alignment -> Center]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
Manipulate[c, 
 Dynamic @
   Grid[{{"Checkbox 1", Row[{Control[{{a, 0, ""}, {1, 0}}], 
       If[a == 1, 
        Control[{{c, {0}, ""}, {1 -> "Edit"}, ControlType -> TogglerBar}], ##&[]]}, 
      Alignment -> Left]}, 
    {"Checkbox 2", Row[{Control[{{b, 0, ""}, {1, 0}}], 
       If[a == 1, "", ##&[]]}, Alignment -> Left]}},
     Alignment -> {Left, Right}], 
 ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is a great solution. I still have, however, two issues: the first is that there is extra horizontal space when Checkbox 1 is selected (see edit section in my question). Second, my code actually has lots of checkboxes and sliders, meaning that I'd have to add that `If` bit to every single control, which would yield a much bigger code. Any way around this? In any case, thanks a lot, this is already pretty useful as it is!

Comment: Could it be that the spacing is related to the natural list bracket spacing from `Row`? I don't know much about it, but maybe it could be compensated with something like a "negative" version of a `Spacer` that would drag Checkbox 1 to the left, but I'd like it to be automatic and resolution/OS independent.

Comment: @sam, please see the update.